# Move out mysql connection into another class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the best way to move database connective outside this class. So that there is only 1  connection per execution. Also any improvements to the below code is welcome.

```
<?php

    $DatabaseConfig = array(
        'username'  =>  'root',
        'password'  =>  'root',
        'host'      =>  'localhost',
        'database'  =>  'live'
    );

    define('APPPATH', '/var/www/');

    require_once APPPATH.'lib/KLogger.php';

    class BaseModel {

/**
 * var $klogger object klogger instance  
 */
        protected $Klogger;

/**
 * var $Mysqli object mysqli instance  
 */
        protected $DBH;

/**
 * function to initiate logger and database
 */         

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->Klogger  = KLogger::instance(APPPATH.'tmp/logs/mysql/', KLogger::INFO);

            $this->initDb();
        }

/**
 * function to initiate database
 */         
        protected function initDb()
        {
            global $DatabaseConfig;


            try{
                $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=".$DatabaseConfig['host'].";dbname=".$DatabaseConfig['database'], 
                                    $DatabaseConfig['username'], $DatabaseConfig['password']);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                 $this->Klogger->logError($e->getMessage());
                 exit;
            };


        }
/**
 * function to initiate database
 */
        protected function fetch($query,$data = array())
        {
            try
            {
                $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($query);
                $STH->execute();

                $result = array();
                while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
                    $result[] =$row;
                }
                return $result;
            }
            catch(Exception $e){

                 $this->Klogger->logError($e->getMessage().' \n Query : '.$query);
                 return false;
            };

        }
/**
 * function to save to database
 */
        protected function save($query,$data = array())
        {

            try
            {
                if(empty($data))
                {
                     throw new Exception('Data Not Passed To save');
                }
                $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($query);
                $STH->execute($data);
                return true;

            }
            catch(Exception $e){

                 $this->Klogger->logError($e->getMessage().' \n Query : '.$query);
                 return false;
            };

        }
    }
?>


<?php

require_once 'base_model.php';

class profile extends BaseModel
{
    function test()
    {

        $data   = $this->fetch("SELECT * FROM users");

        $result = $this->save("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?,?)",array("tow",1)); 

        var_dump($data);

        var_dump($result);

    }
}

$profile = new profile();
$profile->test();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). [Here's](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1304-how-use-singleton-design-pattern.html) an example of a database connection singleton.

Comment: can u explain this code class Database 
{ 
    // Store the single instance of Database 
    private static $m_pInstance; 

    private function __construct() { ... } 

    public static function getInstance() 
    { 
        if (!self::$m_pInstance) 
        { 
            self::$m_pInstance = new Database(); 
        } 

        return self::$m_pInstance; 
    } 
}

Comment: In short, what you get is a class that can only be instanciated once. Instead of calling the constructor (`$db = new Database()`), you use the method `getInstance`, like this: `$db = Database::getInstance()`. That method takes care of creating the object once and returning that same instance every time you call it. In that way, you only connect to the DB once on every request and do all your queries and operations using that connection. I'd suggest you read Wikipedia's article on the Singleton pattern which I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Moving database stuff outside class doesn't seem to be a good solution. Try to use Singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern