# PHP OOP database design

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

OK, this is just a quick question and I might take some slack for this but I'm just looking for a little guidance as I am completely self taught.  I do a lot of reading and try to do a lot of building--I'd say I'm coming into a nice intermediate stage of php, mysql, and web knowledge in general--by no means advanced or overly confident--still learning.

I'm really trying to tackle OOP in PHP and so I want to create a good lean database wrapper for MySQL, just MySQL, I'm most comfortable with MySQL and I dont see any reason to use any other database.  I dont want to create any sort of portability in the design--I want it to be specific to my database; so I dont want to use PDO.

So the question I have as of right now in the beginning is should I create a class that EXTENDS mysqli and then have create model classes for my database tables that extend that base database class?  so class->child = mysqli->DbBase->UsersModel ? This would require a lot of $this statements inside the class, would it not?

Or should I instantiate a mysqli class and pass it to DbBase?

Comment: I really highly recommend you don't use `mysqli`. Its interface has a lot of ugly warts compared to PDO, and PDO is far and away the *standard* modern db API on PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes kind of represent things in the real world (or even imaginary "things"), right? An instance of a DB represents a connection to that db. Has a model something in common with a database connection? Not really. I would suggest to include instances of your database class in those models classes you're going to write, because a model *uses* a database connection to access it's data but *is not* a kind of database connection.

Concerning Mysqli <-> DBClass: That really depends on what you're trying to achieve with that DBClass - does it extend Mysqli with some extra functions or anything? If it doesn't, don't use inheritance there, otherwise you *can* use it.

---

A very basic example, just to give you the idea: (it is actually a simplified but definitely not complete version of the ActiveRecord pattern)

```
abstract class DbTable {
    /* An instance of your DBClass (=Database Connection), to be used if no
     * other connection is specified. */
    protected static $_defaultDbAdapter = null;

    /* The db connection to be used by this instance. */
    protected $_dbAdapter = null;

    /* The name of the table in the database. */
    protected $_tableName = '';

    public static function setDefaultDbAdapter(DbClass $db) {
        self::$_defaultDbAdapter = $db;
    }

    public function setDbAdapter(DbClass $db) {
        $this->_dbAdapter = $db;
    }

    public function getDbAdapter() {
        if (null === $this->_dbAdapter) {
            $this->setDbAdapter(self::$_defaultDbAdapter);
        }
        return $this->_dbAdapter;
    }

    public function insert(array $data) { /*...*/ }
    public function update(array $data, $where) { /*...*/ }
    public function delete($where) { /*...*/ }
    public function select($where) { /* may e.g. return an array of DbTableRow childclass instances */ } 

    // ...
}

class Users extend DbTable {
    protected $_tableName = 'my_users_table';
}

abstract class DbTableRow {
    /* The row itself (may be not yet saved to the db!) */
    protected $_data = array();

    /* The row as it is in the database (to find differences, when calling save()). */
    protected $_cleanData = array();

    /* An instance of the table that this row belongs to. */
    protected $_table = null;

    public function __construct(DbTable $table, array $data = array()) { /*...*/ }
    public function save() { /* uses $this->_table->insert()/update() */ }
    public function __get($key) { /*...*/ }
    public function __set($key, $value) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
}

class User extends DbTableRow { }
```

Usage:

```
// Make a new connection to the database
$db = new DbClass('...'); // or whatever you name that class...

// Set this connection to be the default connection
DbTable::setDefaultDbAdapter($db);

// Create a new user
$users = new Users();
$user = new User($users);
$user->email = 'test@example.com';
$user->save();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I think it was 'most' what I was looking for so far, but I'm not following your model approach.  Wouldn't it make sense to model a table in a class that extend from a data access object where you could easily have methods such as ->save() ?

Comment: That would make sense indeed. But a table class represents a table, and that is also different from a database connection as it uses one to access its data, but isn't really a type of it. I can highly recommend to take a look at the Zend_Framework components Zend_Db and Zend_Db_Table. And I'm gonna add an example to my answer, how I would handle this!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work with OOP, I'd strongly recommend using PDO, because it's the most updated and OO implementation of the MySQL library. I don't think PDO-MySQL is any less MySQL-specific than MySQLi.

In any case, you shouldn't extend PHP's class in this case, you should keep an object with the database connection as a property of your class.

You should also look into the Singleton design pattern, which is really useful in these cases. Take a look at this post from today: [Move out mysql connection into another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637782/move-out-mysql-connection-into-another-class/9637824#comment12234447_9637824)

Comment: Ok thanks this sounds good, but what would be the right way to go about that --> Instantiating the database object outside of my DbBase or model class and then passing it to a function such as the __construct and then saving it as a property or instantiating it inside the __construct initially as a property.  Is there any difference?

Comment: It depends on how you design your application, but I'd say it's best to instantiate the database object inside your constructor. Specially if you want to have a Singleton. Then you can get an instance of your DB connection anywhere without having to deal with db login information, etc.

Comment: alright thanks a lot, i also found a good section in the book Profesional PHP Design Patterns.  I have safari books online so its right here if anyone else has it:  [link](http://abc.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/php/9780470496701)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to learn and understand OOP then I think you should start to learn some PHP frameworks (like Zend Framework) and read it's source codes. I learned lots of things from them.

Comment: yea, that has helped me, im currently viewing all the Yii base classes and trying to learn Yii.